# How do I make the Url.Action method to serialize inner properties?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

Consider I have the following classes as `ViewModels`

```
public class Address
{
    public String Street { get; set; }
}

public class Person()
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a View which Model is `Person`, I can do this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Address.Street)
```

The resulting input name will be `Address.Street` and, when I post it to an Action, the default model binder is able to realize that the input which name is `Address.Street` actually refers to the property `Street` inside the property `Address`.

That works fine.

However, I have a problem when I try to use this:

```
this.Url.Action("MyAction", myPerson)
```

I expect the Url serializer to build a queryString like this: `/person/edit?Address.Street=X` but it actually does't serialize the `Address` property.

Is there something I can do to make the Url serializer to work in this scenario?

Comment: If Address.Street is blank, it won't be included by default when the object is serialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no default solution for it because Url.Actoin internally create RouteValueDictionary from object that you specify (in your case it myPerson). And RouteValueDictionary fill key/value pairs using following method :

```
  private void AddValues(object values) { 
        if (values != null) { 
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(values);
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props) { 
                object val = prop.GetValue(values);
                Add(prop.Name, val);
            }
        } 
    }
```

And as result for address you get following pair { "Address", person.Address }
And finally route just convert value to string and add it to query string  and as result in query string you get ?Adress=[person.Address.ToString()])

I think the simplest way to do it is write a helper which will build RouteValueDictionary from object in way that you need.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this is the solution. Fortunately, I can create an HtmlHelper for Url.Action2 (example name) that turns my object into a RouteDataDictionary and calls the UrlHelper.GenerateUrl() passing the appropriate parameters.